# Rate Limiting using ratelimit lib

Tags: flask, swagger, python-3.6, rate-limiting

I'm trying to add ratelimit my endpoint using https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/. 
The app is in Flask.
My Code looks like

```
@limits(calls=2, period=60)
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, requests.exceptions.RequestException)
@endpoint
def contact():
    <some code to fetch data from DB>
    return "Success", 200
```

This is swagger app. When I hit the endpoint more than 2 times I get , 500 INTTERNAL SERVER ERROR on swagger and in logs I get `ratelimit.exception.RateLimitException: too many calls`. I want to show custom error message on swagger showing that this is because of RateLimitException and then show limits applied. I tried

```
@limits(calls=2, period=60)
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, requests.exceptions.RequestException)
@endpoint
def contact():
    try:
      <some code to fetch data from DB>
      return {"Success"}, 200
    except:
      return {"Rate limit exception"}, 500
```

Above code isn't working. Can I get some help with this. Please let me know if I need to add more info in this.